# How can I color code national vs subnational boundaries in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, administrative-boundaries, borders, boundaries

I'm trying to make a regional map of West Africa at the subnational level. I can't seem to figure out how to distinguish the subnational and national boundaries - right now, they're all black, and I'd like the subnational boundaries to be in a different color than the national boundaries.

Does anyone know how I can do this in QGIS?

Answer (score 4):

A simple way would be to have your national borders in a separate file from your subnational borders.

Here is an example if you use the most-detailed border datasets from Natural Earth Data (http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/). I downloaded both the "Admin 0 - Countries" and "Admin 1- States/Provinces" datasets. They should align perfectly because Natural Earth Data is awesome like that.

I used a simple fill symbol with border for the Admin 1 layer. 
[image: Style for subnational borders]

I then stacked the Admin 0 layer on top using a transparent fill and a different border:

[image: Style for national borders]

Because Natural Earth Data borders at the same scale line up perfectly, the national borders hide the subnational borders below them:

[image]

Alternatively, If you don't want the country borders to continue along the coastlines, you can download the "Admin 0 - Boundary Lines - land boundaries" layer for national boundaries instead:

[image]